# Backup google analytics data

Tags: google-analytics

Is there an application that can easily backup your google analytics profile data to my desktop or would I have to make this service using the API?

Comment: why would you want to backup the google analytics profile data, google lets you access data free forever (assuming they don't discontinue the product)

Comment: The best way to backup Google Analytics data is to keep a copy of the tracking data sent to Google: 

http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/google-analytics-backup-copy

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of any software/scripts to do this, the thing is you wouldn't be able to import the data anyways. So an actual backup wouldn't do anything.

However you can per category use the export function(csv, tsv, tsv for excel and pdf) to start downloading files with your data.
Change the date range and hit export.. and you could a write a script to make it into one single file.

However automation for this I haven't seen before.

edit: Hmm I just see the topic date now... nevermind ;)